# How to preserve datetime with time zone in oracle db?

Tags: java, spring, jaxb2

We are processing different kind of files(xml, csv, excel) where data being sent to us from diff source which are in different timezones. Say for eg India, Australia, Europe(UK,France etc), US, Africa etc. Now when they sent us data, they give us date and time in their timezone and we like to preserve those in oracle db. These servers are located in US EST only.

What is the best practice to preserve these datetime in their timezones in db and when we generate reports we are able to use them based on their country?

We are using JodaTime lib just in case. Other technology we use are JAXB for xml  parsing and spring based app to process files and store data in db. We use java 7 so we cannot use JDK 8 date libs.

Answer (score 0):

Best Approach is to keep the `DateTime` in `UTC`. Keep the `Timezone` in another column (According to your use case +05:00 or Country Name etc). So While retrieving apply the offset according to the stored timezone.

In this case You can also consider things like `Day light Savings` and so on.

**In Oracle**

Check the Option TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006169)

Comment: Viswanath thank you for you response. But I guess i was not clear in my question. We dont want to processing where we have to store TZ in diff col and process dates. Is there anyway where we can just preserver datetime with timezone in single col and when we select and generate json/text file report it gives date in the preservered timezone?

Comment: Yes I added that at last. timestamp with timezone. Please check that :)